# Loading R libraries

Tags: linux, r, libraries, redhat

So I do not have permission to add packages to where `R` stores it's libraries and was wondering if there was a way to add the package to my local directory (say my desktop) and then to run it using `R`.  I tried the following but it failed because it couldn't locate lgfortan

```
install.packages("tgp",lib="/home/bps/Desktop/")
```

Typically the package would be installed into the default directory but that is not an option here for me since I don't have permission to add directories.  Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: R packages without external library dependencies should install in a local directory automatically if you don't have permissions for the system one. You'll need to be able to place `gfortran` (et al) into a local directory and ensure your `PATH` can get to them (and, for some compilations, specify directories for modules & libraries manually or in environment variables. You could also give [packrat](http://rstudio.github.io/packrat/) a go (provided you can install it :-) since it will help keep all dependencies local to your projects.

Comment: @hrbmstr isn't it possible to overcome this by somehow setting some flags like configure? I don't know how to do it and if tgp allows for it, but I think it may be possible (?)

Comment: Use `.libPaths()`. Then R will "know" where to look. And I think this is a duplicate question.